# passing two models from MVC razor view to controller on @html.form submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using @Html.BeginForm in a view in MVC razor to post one entity UserModel to the controller.

So, in controller I have:

```
public ActionResult SaveUser(UserModel user)
{
}
```

What I want is post another related entity i.e UserPrivacyModel to the controller so that in the controller I will be able to receive two objects

```
public ActionResult SaveUser(UserModel user, UserPrivacyModel userPrivacy)
{
}
```

Can it be achieved? If yes, how? and if no, Is there any alternative approach anyone can suggest

Thanks

Comment: yes and no. you cant really send 2 models but you can send a supermodel that has both as members. you want to bind your view to a model that stores both views. then bind your inputs/helpers/controls to the 2 models.

Comment: Above is correct. However, an easier solution is to stick both `UserModel` and `UserPrivacyModel` into a separate model, say: `RegistrationViewModel` and use that model for your view. With that you will be able to use expressions in your html input helpers.

Comment: Thank you Guys.. I got the easier solution by Dmitry. But I did not quite understand what Dave is trying to say regarding binding your view to a model that stores both views

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done:

```
<input type="button" name="user.Name" value="somevalue" />
...

<input type="button" name="userPrivacy.SomeProperty" value="othervalue" />
...
```